# strict $scope to prevent a property jungle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I find that when creating applications using angular the `$scope` starts to feel messy as there's so much added to it, and there's actually no way of restricting the properties and methods assigned to the scope. In my opinion it becomes very hard to keep it clean and overseeable.

I have created a module that wraps around the `$scope` object, which then takes 2 objects to predefine properties and methods that are allowed on the scope, like so (note that the exact code is not the issue here):

```
// set which scope properties are valid. currently returns $scope
// I was not able to properly extend $scope with new getter/setters
// note that this contains the FULL overview of valid properties on scope.
$scope = enforcer.init(
    $scope,
    { "foo": null, "bar": null /* object with valid properties */ }, 
    { "doFoo": null, "doBar": null /* object with valid methods */}
);

// set the actual property on the scope, could be anywhere in the controller
enforcer.set('foo', 'baz');
enforcer.set('doFoo', function () { /* ... */ });

// try to set an invalid property on the scope -> error
enforcer.set('biggle', 'boggle');
```

However, as I'm not overwriting native getters/setters this means I have to call things like `enforcer.set()` to add a variable to the scope. This will in turn match the predefined properties to see if the desired property is actually predefined and will throw an error if it's not. Unfortunately this also kind of breaks my auto-completion in the editor. Next to that, scope references from the HTML are also not checked and can be pretty wild. I could `bind` on anything and not find a typo in the bound var for hours.

I have not been able to find a proper way of redefining the getter/setter of the scope, and even if I did I could not be sure this would not break when angular updates the original `$scope` object.

What are your suggestions on keeping the scope strict and clean? I'd like the scope to feel the same as any variable in javascript, requiring a declaration (i.e. `var foo;` before being allowed to use it.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about.Some code would help.

Comment: It's not code specific. But in a controller I could assign any property to scope (i.e. `$scope.foo = 'a'; $scope.bar = 'b';`) without any regulation on what is added to the scope. From the model I could bind on anything (i.e. `<input ng-model="baz" /><input ng-model="boo" />`, also without regulation. Bound properties don't even have to be in the `$scope` without any error or warning, ever. I could misspell every bind in the model, and not know until careful debugging.

Comment: that's how angular works.You need to be carefull as to how you write you templates.I dont see it as a problem.If you cant track what is inside a scope then create child scopes. A form can have its own controller and wont pollute the parent scope that way.

Comment: I know that is how angular works :) I'm asking about the best way to regulate it. Creating sub-scopes would just make the problem smaller, not really solve it.

Comment: You said you wrote some code to fix your issue then show us  the code then we can discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

The scope should only serve as a wiring tool which links together services, factories and resources. Thus, the rule of thumb is that the scope should do very little, and if you feel that your scope is cluttered by too much variables, it means that probably you should start thinking about refactoring your code.

Read point 3 of this article: [AngularJS antipatterns and pitfalls](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/)